# How fast must an incompressible ball, with mass $M$ and radius $R$, rotate to form a black hole?

Tags: energy, black-holes, angular-momentum, estimation, moment-of-inertia

An incompressible sphere with a uniformly distributed mass $M$ and radius $R$ is rotating in empty space. How fast must the sphere rotate to form a black hole? Will this happen when the kinetic energy of the mass equals the mass to form a black hole with radius $R$, which then is $R_s=\frac{2GM}{c^2}$? What is the total kinetic energy contained in the sphere? We can't use the classical formula for the moment of inertia of a sphere ($I=\frac{2}{5}MR^2$) to calculate the kinetic energy of the sphere and convert that to the mass $M$ to use it in the formula for $R_s$. How can this be done? Is there a relativistic formula to calculate the energy contained in the sphere?

Of course, a rotating (Kerr) black hole is different from a non-rotating one. Can we still use the method above for a rotating black hole?

Comment: Note that increasing the spin for a constant mass moves the sphere *away* from becoming a black hole, not closer. There is a limit to how much spin a Kerr black hole can have, and unless the mass is big enough to start as a black hole it will eventually pass this spin limit and definitely become unable to form a black hole. That there is a lot of kinetic energy does not matter in this case.

Comment: This calculation is *very* theoretical because any real ball will shatter well below relativistic speed. OTOH, that means you *can* use the classical equation to estimate the rotational KE, but it will be tiny relative to the rest mass. Eg, the equatorial speed of the [millisecond pulsar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond_pulsar), [PSR B1257+12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSR_B1257%2B12), is ~$0.007c$, so $\gamma\approx1.000025$ and its rotational KE is around $0.00001$ its rest mass.

Comment: Even within special relativity the first words of your question, *an incompressible sphere* are an impossibility. See [Ehrenfest paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_paradox).

Comment: @AndersSandberg Why does the amount of kinetic energy contained in the volume of the ball not matter?  If the mass is contained in an indestructible shell will the amount of kinetic energy get so high that it becomes equivalent to the mass of a black hole with a Schwarzschild radius R?

Comment: @IlGuercio - In GR kinetic energy does not produce the gravitational effects it would seem it "should" produce. Consider the "paradox" that very fast moving particles do not implode to black holes, dealt with on this SE a few times.